# Как изменить цвет заголовка групп PropertyGrid?

Tags: winforms, vb.net, propertygrid

После обновления Windows 8.1, у `PropertyGrid` заголовки групп стали темными и текст на них перестал быть читабельным.
Можно ли задать цвета группам и если да, то как это сделать программно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве фонового цвета для заголовков категорий `PropertyGrid` использует тот же цвет, что и для границ. Задается он свойством [`LineColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.linecolor(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
propertyGrid.LineColor = Color.AliceBlue
```

В документации по свойству сказано, что по умолчанию используется системный цвет полос прокрутки:

> One of the Color values. The default is the default system color for scroll bars.

Чем и объясняется изменение цвета на разных версиях ОС.

P.S. То, что используется именно `LineColor` я прочитал в документации к [`CategoryForeColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.categoryforecolor(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The background color of category headings is determined by the LineColor property.